# Single aspnet mvc website with single database which will serve multiple domain request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, multi-tenant

I have an ASPNet MVC 4 web application and have a single database with company wise data. I will have multiple companies and they will request to the application using their own company domain. In my database, I keep the company's domain name with the company’s basic.

All the features of my application are common to all companies except the data. As the data is stored company wise, so it is easy to me to get the data using the CompanyId.

My plan is I will host my application to www.mydomain.com. When a company user will request with their domain say www.company.com, it will hit my application which is hosted as www.mydomain.com. After getting a request, my application will get the domain name from the web request (www.company.com) and will find out the CompanyId from the database and will return the requested page with the company’s data only filtering by the CompanyId.

Now my question is
How I will be able to point the company’s domain (www.company.com) to www.mydomain.com, so that when a user will request from www.company.com, it will hit the www.mydomain.com. Here I like to mention that company’s domain (wwww.company.com) is fully dedicated to serve the request from www.mydomain.com. It has no binding with any other websites.  I have no idea about the DNS setup and I am not sure whether I have to change the Routing in my MVC application.
Please help me by suggesting the way around in details.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something pretty much identical to what you are describing and I've used the same  setup. The only thing left is setting up the DNS.

The preferred way to do this is to have www.company.com on a dedicated IP address.

Then, on www.mydomain.com you would create an A-record to point to the same IP address as www.company.com

This way, the requests made to www.mydomain.com will be sent to the same location as www.company.com and you can check the host header to look up the companyId in the database.

If you do not have a dedicated IP address, you can use a CNAME, but you'll only be able to point the "www"-version of www.mydomain.com and not "mydomain.com" (without the "www").

Comment: Actually, I want www.mydomain.com as base web site. As I have 1-100 Companies as my client, they will just use their domain to connect my application which is www.mydomain.com. For a client their domain www.company.com will have no hosting space. They will just use their company domain for branding purpose and their users will not know anything about www.mydomain.com. They will only know their own domain www.company.com. By the way, What about domain Alias? can i set the www.company.com domain as Alias name of www.mydomain.com? What will be happend then?

Comment: Using either an A-record or a CNAME will maintain the www.company.com name in the address bar. No one will ever see "www.mydomain.com" anywhere in the URL.